# Register Spring PropertySource without .properties file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a enhancement. How to setup database configuration when application run at the first time.
If I update db.properties with values which user setup in webpage then tomcat server will be restart automatically. 
**So please advise me how to register these values into spring environment so that datasource-tx-jpa.xml can use something like that: ${db.url} without placeholder db.properties**

**I'm tested as below, but it's not work**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("webform.hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect");
System.setProperties(props);
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = (WebApplicationContext) appContext;
        XmlWebApplicationContext xmlWebApplicationContext = (XmlWebApplicationContext) webApplicationContext;



        xmlWebApplicationContext.setConfigLocations(new String[] {
                "classpath:spring/datasource-tx-jpa.xml",
                "classpath:spring/application-config.xml",
                "/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml" });
        xmlWebApplicationContext.refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically add a PropertySource to the environment before the context is loaded.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
//initialize properties
PropertySource<?> propertySource = new PropertiesPropertySource("myprops", properties);
applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
```

Comment: Where/how would this be configured in the Spring lifecycle?